# Need work around for Pandas "Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp" error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to migrate DB objects (tables and views) from Oracle to SQL Server using DF (read_sql and to_sql), but getting an error

> "pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds
>   nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00"

I found that the issue is due to pandas timestamp limitation. Please suggest some work around

```
df = pd.read_sql(f"select * from {tbl_nm}", orcl, index_col=None)
df = df.replace(np.nan, None)
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
df.to_sql(name=f'{tbl_nm}', con=mssql_db_target, schema=f'{schema}', 
          if_exists='append', index=False)
```

> Error Message: pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
>   pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds
>   nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00

Comment: 9999 is an invalid year. Do you really have that value in the Oracle DB? Also, why not dump an SQL file in Oracle and then load it into SQL server? No Python required.

Comment: its a valid data as these kind of future dates is used in multiple dimensional tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have met same problems, search for hours, and couldn't find any solutions. Therefore I did it my way. It's definitely not a good solution, but I got the job done.

1. Read and save the data into csv,
2. Replace the value of '9999-12-31 00:00:00' to '2099-12-31 00:00:00'
3. read the data from csv into dataframe
4. df.to_sql()

although, i know there's a function

```py
df.somedate = pd.to_datetime(df.somedate, errors = 'coerce')
```

but, I have no ideas of the specific column name of my tables, seems three are too many '9999-12-31 00:00:00'. Hope this will be helpful.

Best